# how prevent rate limit reset after change `X-Real-IP` in request

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, appsettings

I'm using The AspNetCoreRateLimit package and
requests rate limit per times has been controlled but when change X-Real-IP in request then rate limit reset.

its part of my code:

```
"IpRateLimiting": {
    "EnableEndpointRateLimiting": true,
    "StackBlockedRequests": false,
    "RealIpHeader": "X-Real-IP",
    "ClientIdHeader": "X-ClientId",
    "HttpStatusCode": 429,
    "IpWhitelist": [ "127.0.0.1" ],
    "EndpointWhitelist": [ "*:/assets/*" ],
    "ClientWhitelist": [],
.
.
.
}
```

[image]

how can prevent this security issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the settings of nginx in path `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` in the Location section add this line:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rules should be like below.

```
"IpRateLimitPolicies": {
"IpRules": [
  {
    "Ip": "84.247.85.224",
    "Rules": [
      {
        "Endpoint": "*",
        "Period": "1s",
        "Limit": 10
      },
      {
        "Endpoint": "*",
        "Period": "15m",
        "Limit": 200
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Ip": "192.168.3.22/25",
    "Rules": [
      {
        "Endpoint": "*",
        "Period": "1s",
        "Limit": 5
      },
      {
        "Endpoint": "*",
        "Period": "15m",
        "Limit": 150
      },
      {
        "Endpoint": "*",
        "Period": "12h",
        "Limit": 500
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

For more details, please [read  this article](https://riptutorial.com/asp-net-core/example/18611/rate-limiting-based-on-client-ip).